# Где хранить данные при неоднократом исполнении скрипта .php?

Tags: php

Где можно хранить данные, которые будут обрабатываться скриптом, исполняющимся несколько раз подряд?

**Например:**
Есть массив. В нём лежат массивы с данными.
В начале скрипта собирается основной массив массивов со всеми данными.
Далее скрипт, записывает данные из одного из массива в CSV файл.
После этого скрипт, запускается вновь и записывает уже следующий массив данных из общего массива.

Вопрос в том, где можно хранить общий массив данных, чтобы каждый раз не собирать его в начале скрипта, а собрать его при первом исполнении, сохранить и юзать.

Пробовал кэш, БД и сессию, но чёт не нравится и хотелось бы узнать, есть ли ещё какие варианты? Например какой нибудь особенный формат класс, о котором я не в курсе или ещё что-нибудь?

P.S.: Работаю с нативным PHP, не фреймворк

Comment: json-файл какой-нибудь, этого достаточно. `json_encode()`/`json_decode()` на массив этот, и чтение/запись.

Comment: Чем вариант с кэшем не устроил? если объем не большой - сессия, если объем приличный - кэширующие инструменты(например memcached)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков окей, спасибо) объём у меня приличный, поэтому остановился на кэше